# Is using tag values to control access to a resource possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

In an attempt to give an instance access to a specific folder in an s3 bucket, I've got this in a policy:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket/db_backups/${aws:ResourceTag/Name}/*"`

It doesn't work. Documentation for using tags like this is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html

So perhaps what I'm trying to do is not possible.

But I'd rather not create a new role for each instance that needs access to a folder. Is there some other way I can pull this off?

Comment: The ability to control permissions by tag varies by resource type. You certainly can't insert tags into ARNs (as per your example), but some resources allow tags as shown in the examples on the page you linked. You could try a combination of ARN (`arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket/db_backups/*`) and Condition, then see whether it works. You might want to Edit your question to provide details of exactly what you're trying to achieve. For example, you say you'd like to grant an instance access to a folder, but then you reference tags without explaining what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want each instance to be able to backup to its own designated folder in a bucket without giving it access to other folders in the bucket. I could write a separate policy for each instance to accomplish this but I’d rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to write a single policy that applies to multiple IAM Users / IAM Roles.

As shown in that documentation, using a `aws:userid` variable will insert `role-id:ec2-instance-id`. Thus, the instances could be granted access to paths that match their role and instance, such as:

```
s3://bucketname/AROAU2DKSKXYQTOSDGTGX:i-abcd1234/*
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I did not know aws:userid translated to that for each instance. The only downside to this approach is it's not immediately obvious what the path is to the backup dir. But after all this, I may just use the aws backup service instead of rolling my own. It's tough to figure out what is more cost effective, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws:ResourceTag` is not defined for S3 resources. S3 only provides the tag as a policy variable when accessing objects and it is under the variable `s3:ExistingObjectTag`.

I had to do this for a recent engagement and one of things that made this difficult is that not all services supply their tags as a policy variable and those that do all use different names. The `aws:ResourceTag` variable is only provided if the resource you are accessing is KMS and a few other services.

Regardless, I'm not sure if your statement will work. What I think you actually want is to use `aws:PrincipalTag/Name` — i.e. `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::My_Bucket/db_backups/${aws:PrincipalTag/Name}/*"`. This will embed the `Name` tag of the IAM principal — user or role — that is being used to access the resource.

Comment: I tried using PrincipalTag already (it was the first thing I tried). It didn't work either. Sorry, I should have put that in my original post.